# Finder/Disk Utility not showing exFat formatted internal volume

Tags: macos, disk-volume, exfat

I am using OS El Capitan 10.11.6 . I have formatted a partition (D - 90.1 GB) of the internal/builtin SSD SM0256G of my MacBook Pro with exFat, and copied some data onto it. It was working good, but when I restarted my MacBook, the exFat formatted partition D is not showing in Finder. I can't find it in Disk Utility. The space of 90.1 Gb which was allocated to D partition is shown as untitled. My question is: can I recover my data which I have copied on D drive?

[image: Disk Utility]

The `sudo gpt -r show disk0` output is:

```
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
   start       size  index  contents
        0          1         MBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  176054680      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
176464320     262144
176726464   48828120      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
225554584     262144         
225816728  107159736      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
332976464     262144         
333238608  155242608      5  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
488481216    1269536      6  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
489750752     483960      7  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
490234712          7         
490234719         32         Sec GPT table
490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

`sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` output:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
    Starting       Ending
#: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
2: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  176054680] HPFS/QNX/AUX
3: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 176726464 -   48828120] HFS+        
4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 225816728 -  107159736] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

Comment: @klanomath can i recover my data? or restore lost partition ?

Comment: no windows is not installed on my mac, and i have formatted D partition from mac os using disk utilities.

Comment: sudo fdisk ? it will format my drive?

Comment: @klanomath please suggest a solution.

Comment: What's the purpose of the partitions with the index 2,4 (bot exFAT formatted with the names Untitled and E) and index 7 (name F) and do you use FileVault2?